# Mystery with Zend_Locale

Tags: zend-framework, zend-locale

In my application.ini

```
resources.locale.default = "en_EN"
```

in my Bootrstrap.php

```
protected function _initLocaleRegistry()
{
    $locale = new Zend_Locale('en_EN');
    Zend_Locale::setDefault('en_EN');
    Zend_Registry::set('Zend_Locale', $locale);
}
```

but if insert this code in one my simple view:

```
/**@var $locale Zend_Locale **/
$locale = Zend_Registry::get('Zend_Locale');
echo $locale->getLanguage();
```

the output is: **it**

how the hell can?
it off?

Thanks

Comment: I tried this and I am getting `object(Zend_Locale)#14 (1) { ["_locale":protected]=> string(2) "en" } ` . Probably there is something else.

Comment: Probably do a search inside your project for Zend_Locale , may help you.

Comment: research has not borne fruit! :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by inserting changing so application.ini

```
; locale stuff
resources.locale.default = "en_US"
resources.locale.force = true
```